# Rails, Right way to use a controller for the given use case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app I have a Projects Model which has_many Permissions (user_id, project_id).

When an admin is viewing a project, I want to build a link to "Add Members" which would then show a dialog box allowing the admin to add new users to the project.

My question, is for that Add Members dialog, which controller & method should I be using to populate the dialog box?

Comment: Do you mean a model and not a controller? Controllers don't have relationships (has_many).

Comment: Yes I did, will update. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think membership is a better name than permission. Then you have a 'Membership' resource. You can use the standard REST way to operate the resource.
'Add member' is to create a resource. So it happens in MembershipController.create method via a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the Update of your Projects Controller, as you are updating the content for a project resource.

Comment: So Project > Update, which shows the dialog content? And then post to Project Update ?

Comment: I meant POST to project update.  I am not sure how you should handle the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use .erb (embedded Ruby) files for your views. This way you can have a section of the view that is only shown/accessible by an admin.

Example:

```
... some html code ...

<% if an_admin_is_logged_in %>
  ... your admin-specific dialog box and code ...
  ... if this section includes links to actions that should only be accessible by admins
  ... make sure you're using a 'before_filter' in the associated controller to limit access
<% end %>
```

Then you write an action in app/controllers/application_controller.rb similar to ...

```
helper_method :an_admin_is_logged_in

private
  def an_admin_is_logged_in
     ... code that checks that the current user logged in user is an admin
  end
```

Placing the 'an_admin_is_logged_in' action in the application controller makes, this action is available in all views in your project.

Additionally, some authentication plugins/gems such as [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) include these types of things, and may be of some help. There's also [a great Railscast that explains its use](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic).

Comment: Thanks but I'm not struggling with the permissions, that's easy enough with CanCan. My question was when the users clicks Projects, Add Members, and I want to show the Add Members dialog, which controller & method should I be using?

Comment: I don't quite follow then. Your question seems to ask two things: (1) how do you only show the link to "Add members" to admins, and (2) which controller/method to use to populate the list/dialog? Are you asking one of those two questions, both, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an edit to the Project (i.e. you're editing the permissions on a project), then you could use the 'edit' action to populate the dialog, and a PUT to the 'update' action to save the changes.

You could also write an admin-specific action called "edit_permissions", which populates the dialog box, then PUT the changes to the 'update' action.